# Synchronised instance methods in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

From some internet source

> Here is a synchronized instance method:

```
public synchronized void add(int value){

  this.count += value;
}
```

> Notice the use of the synchronized keyword in the method declaration. This tells Java that the method is synchronized.
>   A synchronized instance method in Java is synchronized on the instance (object) owning the method. Thus, each instance has its synchronized methods synchronized on a different object: the owning instance. Only one thread can execute inside a synchronized instance method. If more than one instance exist, then one thread at a time can execute inside a synchronized instance method per instance. One thread per instance.

Here's my understanding. If I have a runnable object, that contains an instance of the class containing the above add method, then

Case 1 : I have two threads, each having the ***same*** instance of class containing the add method, then only one will be able to execute the above add method at a time. Hence if one thread calls `add` then it CAN NOT be pre empted before it finishes the execution?

Case 2 : If both my threads have two ***different*** instances of the class containing the add method, then it synchronisation does not really play any role in this case. The two of them will execute, as if synchronisation was not applied at all.

Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: yes, you got it. But keep in mind, that for case1, the other thread could modify `count` from another method. (maybe `add2`) You could also synchronize property access, using the `synchronized(property){ }` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however

> then it CAN NOT be pre empted before it finishes the execution?

A lock doesn't stop a thread being pre-empted, but it does stop any other thread from obtaining the same lock. i.e. it looks the same, even though the thread can stop for a short time while holding a lock.

> as if synchronisation was not applied at all.

The difference is that without `synchronized` it would be much faster. As it is such a simple operation.  If you were doing something less trivial, the cost of synchronization would be relatively small.  In any case, correctness is more important than speed in almost all cases.

Comment: Ohh ok. so it can be pre empted, but if the other thread tries to call the same function add, then that is not going to happen.Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I would say code is "much faster" without synchronized.  I'd say "somewhat faster".  Modern JVMs have really optimized synchronization.

Comment: @user949300 They have and for most use cases it makes little difference, unless the operation is trivial such as an `+=` in which case the synchronization is many time more expensive. Certainly correctness is more important that speed.

Comment: @hilAs correct. BTW using AtomicInteger or AtomicLong is much faster, more scalable and thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is largely correct.  (see Peter's answer).

Here's a (silly) example to elaborate.

```
public class Person {
   private String firstName = "?";  // set an initial value
   private String lastName = "?";

   public void setName(String first, String last) {
      this.firstName = first;
      this.lastName = last;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return firstName + " " + lastName ;
   }
}
```

Since neither method is synchronized, if one thread is calling `setName("John", "Doe")` at the same time another is calling `toString()`, it is *possible* for the `setName` to be pre-empted in the middle, and for toString() to be called, with the name to be only "half-set".  So `toString()` could print "John ?".

If both methods are synchronized, the call to `toString()` will occur either *completely before*, or *completely after*, the call to `setName()`'.  If setName() was preempted in the middle, toString() will wait until setName is completed.  So `toString()` will either print "? ?" or "John Doe".

Synchronization may also be required for the Java Memory Model to make sure that changes made in one thread are seen by another thread.  But that is getting more advanced...

Comment: If both the methods were synchronized, then they still acquire the same lock right? i.e. the same instance of the class, wont be able to call either of the methods.

Comment: Correct.  In this example, that specific instance of Person provides the lock.  If a different instance of Person just got married and was changing from "Jane","Smith" to "Jane", "Smith-Jones", that would not affect the lock on the John Doe instance.